# QuillJS 'Bubble' Tooltip appears offscreen

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I am currently developing a Webapp and I am trying to use QuillJS as a WYSIWYG Editor. I am trying to use the 'Bubble' theme as it fits nicely with the rest of my webapp, however when the tooltip is supposed to appear it does not appear on the screen and after checking using the Development console I found that the tooltip is being displayed with a `Top` value of somewhere around -700 to -1000 and I have absolutely no idea why.

I have tried using an element that was high-up in the HTML Heirarchy in case a parent div was messing something up but that did not solve my problem either.

Can anyone tell me why the tooltip appears so far off the screen?

Here is a JSFiddle with the current state of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/RBrNx/nwozxLzz/

Please Note: Most of my webapp does not function or look great in the JSFiddle, this is not an issue as most of the functionality involves a local database.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the `bounds` option，set offset parent

[bounds](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#bounds)

Comment: can you update the jsfiddle with the bounds option - that will make it crystal clear